# remove nested array from json array

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

How do i go about returning only the json without the [] from a Mysql multiple query?

I have this as an SQL Query

```
app.get('/api/v1/admin/getAllUsers',async function (req,res,next){
    try {

        if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ') || !req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]) {
            return res.status(422).json({ message: 'Please Provide Token!' })
        }

        dbConn.query('select * from fasta_users; select * from fasta_logistics; select * from fasta_admin_users;select * from fasta_riders;', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'users list' });
        });

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
})
```

having run this, I get this as response :

```
{
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fastaUserId": "",
                "fullname": "John Qasim",
                "email": "j_qasim001@aol.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$iAzLsIEcOJpDSSgdUmJBR.e8pWdieUg7N4bFiW0lkgBsQQDA6DwPG",
                "state": "Imo",
                "role": "Customers",
                "city": "Owerri",
                "phone_num": "08076631261",
                "created_at": "2022-05-17T15:58:26.000Z"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fastaUserId": "",
                "fullname": "alex roman",
                "email": "alex.roman@juno.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$sXpfYaQQIwoBf1KMaPrgT.PioHY4Y6SXD1lpheDB9EPTwfRtsg1p.",
                "state": "Lagos",
                "city": "city",
                "phone_num": "08111111111",
                "company_type": "Registered",
                "company_name": "Polaris Shipping Inc.",
                "company_regnum": "RC-123456",
                "c_license": 1,
                "role": "Delivery man",
                "l_licensenumber": "LAG-2372328",
                "company_address": "150 Wole Madariola Close",
                "num_employees": "200",
                "company_nature": "Sole Propietorship",
                "created_at": "2022-05-17T15:57:41.000Z"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fastaUserId": "",
                "fullname": "John Legend",
                "email": "john.legend@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$KrW0YKsJmvlp2z5uF4V10uLIjcPpSl1ba/LiWuiRpaLs/XRmguXDy",
                "phone_num": "0188272610",
                "avatar": "test_pic",
                "role": "Administrator",
                "status": "Active",
                "created_at": "2022-05-11T18:48:39.000Z"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "Name": "Karen Mitchelle",
                "RidersID": "FR-60842",
                "Status": "Active",
                "email": "k.m.boon@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$PCTK8okWO/ApoNSgXXTIl.oxzwqf.zlHHJaEvxtfxpUrnI1IaGNQC",
                "phone": "08128829102",
                "No_deliveries": "200",
                "rating": "5",
                "state": "Lagos",
                "city": "Lagos",
                "role": "Rider",
                "address": "150 Wole Kolawole Str. Lagos Nigeria",
                "bike_manufacturer": "Suzuki",
                "bike_model": "Suzuki 400",
                "bike_year": "2012",
                "engine_power": "HP8",
                "bike_color": "red",
                "license_number": "SMK900-LA",
                "license_expiry": "2027-05-01",
                "vehicle_id": "LA8373Q2",
                "created_at": "2022-05-17T15:59:22.000Z"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "message": "users list"
}
```

I just want it to return just the json object alone. How is this possible?
Please I need a guide with this,How can I get this resolved? I need a guide with this.

is there a way to make it be like this :

```
{
  "error":false,
  "data":{
                "id": 1,
                "fastaUserId": "",
                "fullname": "John Qasim",
                "email": "j_qasim001@aol.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$iAzLsIEcOJpDSSgdUmJBR.e8pWdieUg7N4bFiW0lkgBsQQDA6DwPG",
                "state": "Imo",
                "role": "Customers",
                "city": "Owerri",
                "phone_num": "08076631261",
                "created_at": "2022-05-17T15:58:26.000Z",
    
        {
                "id": 1,
                "fastaUserId": "",
                "fullname": "alex roman",
                "email": "alex.roman@juno.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$sXpfYaQQIwoBf1KMaPrgT.PioHY4Y6SXD1lpheDB9EPTwfRtsg1p.",
                "state": "Lagos",
                "city": "city",
                "phone_num": "08111111111",
                "company_type": "Registered",
                "company_name": "Polaris Shipping Inc.",
                "company_regnum": "RC-123456",
                "c_license": 1,
                "role": "Delivery man",
                "l_licensenumber": "LAG-2372328",
                "company_address": "150 Wole Madariola Close",
                "num_employees": "200",
                "company_nature": "Sole Propietorship",
                "created_at": "2022-05-17T15:57:41.000Z"
            },

    
         {
                "id": 1,
                "fastaUserId": "",
                "fullname": "John Legend",
                "email": "john.legend@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$KrW0YKsJmvlp2z5uF4V10uLIjcPpSl1ba/LiWuiRpaLs/XRmguXDy",
                "phone_num": "0188272610",
                "avatar": "test_pic",
                "role": "Administrator",
                "status": "Active",
                "created_at": "2022-05-11T18:48:39.000Z"
            },

            {
                "id": 1,
                "Name": "Karen Mitchelle",
                "RidersID": "FR-60842",
                "Status": "Active",
                "email": "k.m.boon@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2a$12$PCTK8okWO/ApoNSgXXTIl.oxzwqf.zlHHJaEvxtfxpUrnI1IaGNQC",
                "phone": "08128829102",
                "No_deliveries": "200",
                "rating": "5",
                "state": "Lagos",
                "city": "Lagos",
                "role": "Rider",
                "address": "150 Wole Kolawole Str. Lagos Nigeria",
                "bike_manufacturer": "Suzuki",
                "bike_model": "Suzuki 400",
                "bike_year": "2012",
                "engine_power": "HP8",
                "bike_color": "red",
                "license_number": "SMK900-LA",
                "license_expiry": "2027-05-01",
                "vehicle_id": "LA8373Q2",
                "created_at": "2022-05-17T15:59:22.000Z"
            }
 
      }

}
```

**Edits**

My code is Looking like this now :

```
app.get('/api/v1/admin/getAllUsers',async function (req,res,next){
    try {

        if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ') || !req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]) {
            return res.status(422).json({ message: 'Please Provide Token!' })
        }

        dbConn.query('select * from fasta_users; select * from fasta_admin_users;select * from fasta_riders;', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            const infoz = results.data.map(arr =>arr[0]);
            return res.send({ error: false, data: infoz, message: 'users list' });
        });

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
})
```

It still returns the nested array.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and get first `user` from nested array using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const response = {error: false,data: [[{id: 1,fastaUserId: '',fullname: 'John Qasim',email: 'j_qasim001@aol.com',password: '$2a$12$iAzLsIEcOJpDSSgdUmJBR.e8pWdieUg7N4bFiW0lkgBsQQDA6DwPG',state: 'Imo',role: 'Customers',city: 'Owerri',phone_num: '08076631261',created_at: '2022-05-17T15:58:26.000Z',},],[{id: 1,fastaUserId: '',fullname: 'alex roman',email: 'alex.roman@juno.com',password: '$2a$12$sXpfYaQQIwoBf1KMaPrgT.PioHY4Y6SXD1lpheDB9EPTwfRtsg1p.',state: 'Lagos',city: 'city',phone_num: '08111111111',company_type: 'Registered',company_name: 'Polaris Shipping Inc.',company_regnum: 'RC-123456',c_license: 1,role: 'Delivery man',l_licensenumber: 'LAG-2372328',company_address: '150 Wole Madariola Close',num_employees: '200',company_nature: 'Sole Propietorship',created_at: '2022-05-17T15:57:41.000Z',},],[{id: 1,fastaUserId: '',fullname: 'John Legend',email: 'john.legend@gmail.com',password: '$2a$12$KrW0YKsJmvlp2z5uF4V10uLIjcPpSl1ba/LiWuiRpaLs/XRmguXDy',phone_num: '0188272610',avatar: 'test_pic',role: 'Administrator',status: 'Active',created_at: '2022-05-11T18:48:39.000Z',},],[{id: 1,Name: 'Karen Mitchelle',RidersID: 'FR-60842',Status: 'Active',email: 'k.m.boon@gmail.com',password: '$2a$12$PCTK8okWO/ApoNSgXXTIl.oxzwqf.zlHHJaEvxtfxpUrnI1IaGNQC',phone: '08128829102',No_deliveries: '200',rating: '5',state: 'Lagos',city: 'Lagos',role: 'Rider',address: '150 Wole Kolawole Str. Lagos Nigeria',bike_manufacturer: 'Suzuki',bike_model: 'Suzuki 400',bike_year: '2012',engine_power: 'HP8',bike_color: 'red',license_number: 'SMK900-LA',license_expiry: '2027-05-01',vehicle_id: 'LA8373Q2',created_at: '2022-05-17T15:59:22.000Z',},],],message: 'users list',}

response.data = response.data.map(([user]) => user)

console.log(response)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Also you can use [Array#flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const response = {error: false,data: [[{id: 1,fastaUserId: '',fullname: 'John Qasim',email: 'j_qasim001@aol.com',password: '$2a$12$iAzLsIEcOJpDSSgdUmJBR.e8pWdieUg7N4bFiW0lkgBsQQDA6DwPG',state: 'Imo',role: 'Customers',city: 'Owerri',phone_num: '08076631261',created_at: '2022-05-17T15:58:26.000Z',},],[{id: 1,fastaUserId: '',fullname: 'alex roman',email: 'alex.roman@juno.com',password: '$2a$12$sXpfYaQQIwoBf1KMaPrgT.PioHY4Y6SXD1lpheDB9EPTwfRtsg1p.',state: 'Lagos',city: 'city',phone_num: '08111111111',company_type: 'Registered',company_name: 'Polaris Shipping Inc.',company_regnum: 'RC-123456',c_license: 1,role: 'Delivery man',l_licensenumber: 'LAG-2372328',company_address: '150 Wole Madariola Close',num_employees: '200',company_nature: 'Sole Propietorship',created_at: '2022-05-17T15:57:41.000Z',},],[{id: 1,fastaUserId: '',fullname: 'John Legend',email: 'john.legend@gmail.com',password: '$2a$12$KrW0YKsJmvlp2z5uF4V10uLIjcPpSl1ba/LiWuiRpaLs/XRmguXDy',phone_num: '0188272610',avatar: 'test_pic',role: 'Administrator',status: 'Active',created_at: '2022-05-11T18:48:39.000Z',},],[{id: 1,Name: 'Karen Mitchelle',RidersID: 'FR-60842',Status: 'Active',email: 'k.m.boon@gmail.com',password: '$2a$12$PCTK8okWO/ApoNSgXXTIl.oxzwqf.zlHHJaEvxtfxpUrnI1IaGNQC',phone: '08128829102',No_deliveries: '200',rating: '5',state: 'Lagos',city: 'Lagos',role: 'Rider',address: '150 Wole Kolawole Str. Lagos Nigeria',bike_manufacturer: 'Suzuki',bike_model: 'Suzuki 400',bike_year: '2012',engine_power: 'HP8',bike_color: 'red',license_number: 'SMK900-LA',license_expiry: '2027-05-01',vehicle_id: 'LA8373Q2',created_at: '2022-05-17T15:59:22.000Z',},],],message: 'users list',}

response.data = response.data.flat()

console.log(response)
```

Comment: please see Edits.

Comment: user? what if its not defined?

Comment: Added documentation Destructuring assignment to create `user`

Comment: its still the same, still returns nested array for json

Comment: Your edited `response` is invalid object.. I think the best is to work with an array of `user`s objects

Comment: flat did not change, still returns the json arrays []

Comment: says undefined for both map and flat